# GET request via python script with access token

Tags: python, get, postman, access-token

I'm facing some difficulties executing GET request with access token via python.
For some reason when I execute the request from POSTMAN I get the expected result, however, when using python I get connection error :

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I believe that my script is being blocked by the server to prevent scrapping attempts, but I'm not sure.
This is what I'm running via **POSTMAN** :

```
https://www.operation.io/web/alerts?access_token=6ef06fee265de1fa640b6a444ba47--z&envId=58739be2c25e76a202c9dd3e&folderId=active&sortBy=status
```

And this is what I'm running from inside the **script** :

```
response = requests.get('https://www.operation.io/web/alerts', headers={'Authorization': 'access_token 6ef06fee265de1fa640b6a444ba47--z'})
```

Please notice that the url and the access token are not real, so please don't try to use.
How can I make it work via the script and not only via postman?
Thank you for your help/

Comment: `'Authorization': '6ef06fee265de1fa640b6a444ba47--z'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without actually being able to test the solutions, but I would suggest 2 hacks that worked for me in the past:

1. Change "Authorization" to "authorization"
2. Change "6ef06fee265de1fa640b6a444ba47--z" to "Token 6ef06fee265de1fa640b6a444ba47--z" (add a space as well)

Put it all together:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.operation.io/web/alerts', headers={'authorization': 'Token 6ef06fee265de1fa640b6a444ba47--z'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since via postman you're sending the token as query param(as opposed to header), you can try this :

```
response = requests.get('https://www.operation.io/web/alerts', params={'access_token': '6ef06fee265de1fa640b6a444ba47--z'})
```

Assuming the API you're using accepts it as query param rather than as headers (which is my guess from the postman request)

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, and still getting the same error. thanks for the reply.